# instaling nodejs and problems with heroku

Tags: nodejs

I am trying to install node js from https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/

After I installed `curl` and `python-software-properties`
I have problem with this command:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
```

I have this output:

```
...

Err:8 https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stabile/apt ./ Packages
  404  Not Found

...

W: The repository 'https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stabile/apt ./ Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stabile/apt/./Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Error executing command, exiting
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go to `System Settings->Software & Updates`. Then you select the `Ubuntu Software` tab and uncheck items with link is:

```
http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu xenial Release
http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu xenial Release
http://ppa.launchpad.net/boomaga/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease
http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release
http://ppa.launchpad.net/me-davidsansome/clementine-dev/ubuntu xenial InRelease
```

After uncheking it, you run `sudo apt update` and you'll be able to update your system.

For more details you can reading link: [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists)

Comment: Before I read your answer I realized that I had nodejs old version. I updated it and then it worked nice. As you saw i had another problem too which you resolved. When I'm typing `sudo apt-get update`, I don't have errors anymore. Thank you!